# ionic-native googleplus login issue on android device (ionic 2)

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to integrate g+ login in my app. I have followed the below steps:

First, installed ionic-navtive gplus plugin using: `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`

used reversed client id generated from `console.developers.google.com`. its format is `xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`.

then on click of login button trying g+ native call. here is my ts code:

```
googleLogin() {
    this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClintId':'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com ',
    }).then((res) => {
      alert("Login successfull: " + res);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }).catch((err) => {
      alert("Login unsuccessfull: " + err);
    });
}
```

when trying the above code, its going to error block and printing:

> Login unsuccessfull:17

I followed: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-google-login

Comment: Have you configured `Android Signing Certificate SHA-1` in developer console?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put webClientId in `GooglePlus.login()`.

Your login method should be (if no additional options)-

```
GooglePlus.login({}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**iOS**

You need to put `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in `config.xml` for iOS.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.967272422526-vu37jlptokv45glo2kciu9o2rddm7gte" />
</plugin>
```

To find you `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`, in developer console go to credentials and click on created iOS credential and `Download Plist`.

[image]

**Android**

For android you don't need any id, it works on `Signing-certificate fingerprint`, make sure you `Signing-certificate fingerprint` and `Package name` are correct while creating `oauth client id`.

[image]

If you are not signing your apk with any created keystore file then take `SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint` of default debug.keystore file.

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\Username\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

I have used most common path of `debug.keystore` (windows). It might be different for you, just look for `.android` dir.

Comment: Yes, when i run the application in android device

Comment: "both are same"

Comment: package name is also same as config.xml and also check on android device it shows error

Comment: Where you have deployed your APK on device or on emulator?

Comment: in android device

Comment: Try reinstalling plugin and platform. Otherwise if you have followed the answer correctly then all is good at code side.

Comment: please can you share any link?

Comment: check plugin's documentation - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Comment: Already used this plugin and also add the plugin in my ionic app by using this command "cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid" and when run the apk in android device it gives error "17"

Comment: Can you just provide me the command to generate Certificate fingerprints SHA1 for "release" and "debug"

Comment: Stuck in zipalign "This signs the apk in place. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK. The zipalign tool can be found in /path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign. For example, on OS X with Android Studio installed, zipalign is in ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign:"

Comment: complete the steps given in "Android Publishing" given in the provided link "   
ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html" and run the application in my android device but still same error comming